error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
I did "git add ." and "git commit" on a project and every time I push this, its unsuccessful with this message being displayed:
Enumerating objects: 64387, done.
Counting objects: 100% (64387/64387), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (49041/49041), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (64387/64387), 3.06 GiB | 17.57 MiB/s, done.
Total 64387 (delta 13950), reused 64143 (delta 13706), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
Writing objects always gets stuck at 92% and then RPC error is displayed.
I have tried "git config --global http.postBuffer XXX" with XXX values upto 2 GB.
Still doesn't work.
Please help me solve this

GitHub has a hard limit on the size of pushes that's 2 GiB.  Any push larger than this will be rejected.
In your case, the size of what you're pushing is over 3 GiB.  If this is all one commit, then the commit is too large, and you'll need to split it into smaller ones.  Note that you cannot do this by simply creating new commits on top of the existing one, since the entire history you're pushing matters.
If there are multiple commits, you need to push them incrementally.  This answer provides an example of how you might do that.  Note that you'll need to adjust the number of commits in that list to be smaller if you have fewer, larger commits.
According to the Git FAQ, the http.postBuffer option is only needed if you have a server or proxy that is extremely ancient or extremely broken, and GitHub is neither.  All setting it serves to do is waste memory in the vast majority of cases, so you should unset it.

http.postBuffer helped me in the past with github

You almost certainly had an intermittent problem or a broken proxy, such as a non-default antivirus or firewall.  I assure you that it does not fix general push problems and should not be used in the general case; I contribute to Git and wrote the FAQ entry based on personal knowledge about how the code and the HTTP protocol work.
